# In WebBluetooth development, How do i know UUIDs for services and characteristics that is offered by the device BLE peripheral?

Tags: javascript, mobile, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt, web-bluetooth

I am assigned to use WebBluetooth functionality to connect to a Bluetooth BLE Printer and do some PRINTING.

Upon reading documentations, i figured that the way to do this is through some web bluetooth libraries that will enable you to CONNECT -> DISCOVER SERVICE -> DISCOVER CHARACTERISTIC and operate the manipulation on that.

My problem is to access these, in sample codes i see they put HEX characters for filtering.

***My question now is, how do i know the CHARACTERISTICS UUIDs and SERVICE UUIDs on my BLE Printer so that i can control it to do some printing?***

I would really appreciate any inputs regarding this.

Comment: did u found how to get uuids and service uuids from ble printer